# Product filter in PHP from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have MySQL table with columns brand,model,year,name,description and I want to make 3 level drop down filter.

```
First dropdown > Brand
Second dropdown > Model (only when brand selected)
Third dropdown > Year (only when model selected)
Save button.
```

Sorry if it's unclear. I'm just a begginer and looking for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this plugin
http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown
it works same as you required.

Answer (score 0):

Post any piece of your code of html and php so the answer can be more familiary with it.